# How to find the source code and the file which contains it for hadoop HAR?

Tags: hadoop

I am a student learning Hadoop. Currently working on the small file issue. I would like to understand the code for Hadoop archive(HAR). But I do not know where to look for the source code?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a million.

Madhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the code of hadoop project is available on [Github](https://github.com/apache/hadoop) to view and download.
You should take a look and then raise a relevant query if needed.

Comment: Got it under "https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/HarFileSystem.java". Thanks Nitin